# How to send large video file using Flask send_file() function

Tags: video, flask, file-transfer

I want to sent large video file using Slack send_file() API. However the length of the file sent does not match with the original file. It always few hundred bytes less in size. Not sure what I am missing. 
Any help is appreciated.

The server program is written based on Flask + python3 environment.
Here is the code snippet I have tried:

```
@app.route('/download_file')
def download_file():
  try:
    f = request.files['file']
    print("File name :", f.filename)
    path = "/home/juno/app_server/" + f.filename
    print ("Path = " + path)
    file_size =  os.path.getsize(f.filename)
    print("File size :", file_size)

    return send_file(path, attachment_filename=f.filename, as_attachment=True)
  except BaseException as e:
     print (e)
     return("<h1>Exception: Download operation failed</h1>")
```

The original file size : 176331761

The original file information :

Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from '160409_A_015.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : mp42
    minor_version   : 0
    compatible_brands: mp42mp41
    creation_time   : 2017-06-23 18:12:28
  Duration: 00:00:38.10, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 37020 kb/s
    Stream #0:0(eng): Video: h264 (Main) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p(tv, bt709), 1920x1080, 37015 kb/s, 29.97 fps, 29.97 tbr, 30k tbn, 59.94 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2017-06-23 18:12:29
      handler_name    : Alias Data Handler
      encoder         : AVC Coding

=======================================

The sent file size : 176332165

The sent file information :

[mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2 @ 0x1f67340] Format mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2 detected only with low score of 1, misdetection possible!
[mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2 @ 0x1f67340] moov atom not found
s3.mp4: Invalid data found when processing input

**MODIFICATION:**
It seems that flask send_file() send file content as normal data, not as video data.

> $ file h2.mp4 ===> h2.mp4: data (downloaded file)
>
> $ file 160409_A_015.mp4  ===>   160409_A_015.mp4: ISO Media, MP4 v2 [ISO
>   14496-14]  (original file)

Comment: have you tried a smaller file with success? Perhaps try looking at using flask's `send_from_directory` function instead of send_file.  Its safer in this case.  Also, maybe don't use 'attachment_filename' option. I do something similar to you, and this is my call.  `send_from_directory(realdir, name, as_attachment=True)`

Comment: also, if you are setting 'USE_X_SENDFILE' to True, that might be a problem if your web server doesn't support X-Sendfile.  If you are using the built in flask web server for testing, that doesn't support X-Sendfile. [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19421014/error-occurred-in-mobile-when-send-video-using-send-file-in-python-flask) might be helpful